# Firemonkey Android 9 Orientation sensor not working in Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: delphi, sensors, gyroscope, delphi-10.3-rio

i'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the android device orientation.
the sensor itself is a piece of work. The tilting and heading shows NAN. the gyro dose not work either. i've upgraded to Delphi 10.3.3 but Orientation sensor still not working ! . 
some gut tried to use the AndroidApi senors but still the Magnetometer dosent work ! [Fusion Sample](https://github.com/omarreis/FiremonkeySensorFusion)

is there any solution of fix for this problem ?! or maybe an implemnation of Androidapi gyro sensor.

Comment: Have your tried other apps that use the same sensors? Do they seem to report accurate values, or at least react to changes in the values? To rule out the possibility that maybe your device just has faulty sensors

Comment: Yes i did, the `SensorInfo` in `\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services` + `\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\OrientationSensor` + `\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\Gyroscope` all dosent work . i tried bunch of comapss app from google play and all works @RemyLebeau

Comment: i tired some senor test apps and gyro and orientation sensors dosent work ! , but how it works in the Compass ?! @RemyLebeau

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122825/delphi-androidapi-motion-detection

Comment: The solution you mention is mine. It works, at least for the phones I tested (S9, A7, iphone). For Android is uses sensor code from DelphiWorlds.  Note that Android magnetic sensor sometimes stops for no apparent reason. Check other apps that use it ( compass apps). It may be in need a figure 8 calibration, or is detecting magnetic interference. Sometimes booting the device helps.

Comment: check this sample app: https://github.com/omarreis/BoatAttitude